# disk space issue

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu server 20.04.2 running on a VM on a Windows Server hypervisor. The only thing this VM is doing is running a Unifi controller. When I try to load the GUI of the controller, I get a 404 error. I tried to run apt-get update on the VM and I get write error - no space left on device. df -h yields:

[image]

I can tell from reading other questions on here that there's a problem, but being very new to Ubuntu, I'm not sure what the solution would be.

Comment: Reboot, then delete some unnecessary files?

Comment: If you're still using Ubuntu 20.04.2 that means you've not applied security fixes since mid 2021 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.3, but installed systems upgraded **before** that ISO release) so this is likely not a new issue (*is the system maintained?*); I hope its kept off-line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: The web interface for unifi controller runs on port 8443... but that might not be your problem as it looks like you need to sort out your disk space issue